# Bootstrap datetimepicker next month can be selected only once

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a `Datetimepicker` configured so that it shows only months. Also, user is able to select only future months. All works until I select next month (current month + 1) then another month. After these steps made I cannot select the *next month* anymore.

[image]

Is it a bug in `Datetimepicker` itself or I'm doing something wrong? 
[Here is the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6hjsre7y/11/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a bug with bootstrap's datetimepicker when you allow only months but the `minDate` is not the first day of your month.
You can fix this by using:

```
minDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() + 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/24L6rysx/

Comment: Since the datetimepicker depends from moment, you can also use `minDate: moment().startOf('month').add(1, 'months')` to achieve the same result.